# Join Computer to Domain in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, dns, domain, windows-server-2016

I'm a little confused, I've been playing around with a home lab, and I am looking to add a laptop to the domain that I have created for test purposes.

I have been reading some articles, and some of the just tell you to add the Device to the Domain, and others tell me to first change the adapter settings to point to the DNS server, then add the domain.

I am just trying to understand why there are differences?
Does it depend on the setup?

Regards.

Comment: What's provoking the question? What happens when you try it? Is it not working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Windows Domain join is heavily reliant on DNS. If you aren't using your Windows Server to also do DHCP (and provide DNS) then your clients won't get the correct DNS server to allow the domain join to find your DC - thus you'll receive an error that the domain join couldn't find a DC. OR, you would need to manually configure your clients to use the DC as their primary DNS server, and then do the domain join. Been there, done that.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a good explanation. I will have to manually configure the DNS, because I am still using my router as my primary DHCP.

Comment: If I wanted the server as the primary DHCP, would I have to disable DHCP on router in order to stop confusion?